# Error with std::getline

Tags: c++, getline

So this is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void print_file(const ifstream& dat_in)
{
    if(!dat_in.is_open())
        throw ios_base::failure("file not open");

    string buffer;
    while(getline(dat_in, buffer));  //error here
}

int main()
{
    ifstream dat_in("name_of_the_file.txt");

    try{
        print_file(dat_in);
    }
    catch(ios_base::failure exc){
        cout << exc.what() << endl;
    }
}
```

And I get an error that no instance of overloaded function `std::getline` matches the argument list.
I did this line of code a thousand of times, what is the problem now ...

> ```
> 3 IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "getline" matches the argument list
>         argument types are: (const std::ifstream, std::string)  
> Error 1   error C2665: 'std::getline' : none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The culprit is the `const`:

```
 void print_file(const std::ifstream& dat_in)
              // ^^^^^
```

Of course the `std::ifstream`'s state is changed when reading data from it, thus it cannot be `const` in that context. You should simply change your function signature to

```
 void print_file(std::ifstream& dat_in)
```

to get this working.

---

BTW the function name `print_file` is pretty confusing for a function that actually reads from a file.

Answer (score 2):

the problem is here

```
void print_file(const ifstream& dat_in)
```

`getline` necessarily changes the `stream` that is passed-in. So change the above to (remove `const`)

```
void print_file(ifstream& dat_in)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is passing a reference to a `const ifstream` parameter as the first parameter to `std::getline()`. Since `std::getline()` modifies its input stream parameter, it cannot have a `const` reference as the first parameter.

The error message from the compiler included a list of all the parameters, and it should've indicated that the first parameter is a `const` reference.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, pass and return all streams types as reference, neither const or by-value. Remember that const refers to the object, not the file and the object has many things that could change even if the file is a read-only file.